# Web push doesn't work on IOS 16.4 after some time

Tags: progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari

Web push doesn't work on IOS 16.4 after some time.

We have used web pushes on IOS for one and half month and sometimes users complain that push stop working. Users hadn't open pwa for long time before this.

I have two theories:

1. Subscription just silently expire and endpoint stop working;
2. Service worker doesn't wake up after some time of inactivity.

Some context:

1. We implement resubscribe on every pwa start;
2. We found bug when after cross-domain redirect (authorization) safari doesn't wake up service worker (there is just no active service worker in debugger);

I was able to reproduce this bug, my steps:

1. install pwa and subscribe to push notifications;
2. close pwa;
3. wait 3 weeks (!);
4. push doesn't work;

after this steps I expected to see no service worker alive, but after opening the pwa with connected debugger I found that `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.state` is `"activated"`.

Comment: I cannot get my web push to work on IOS at all. It works fine on android phones and windows computers. Did you guys have to do anything special to get it working on IOS?

Comment: It requires IOS 16.4+ and installed PWA then it works same like in android.

Comment: How do you install the PWA? On google / Android devices it gives a pop-up prompt when you visit the page on IOS it does not and I haven't been able to see where I go to install the pwa on the device.

Comment: In Safari: Share -> add to home screen

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the exact same problem, the subscription info were initialized by unknown reason.

but it seems that after iOS 16.5.1(c) update the problems were gone.

---

after iOS 16.6 update the problem reoccured.
i guess i was lucky